# Excel COUNTIFS criteria... I want to count all names in range1 (not a specific name), that meet specific criteria from range2. How do I do this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For reference, using COUNTIFS is required and should not be used in combination with other functions.

I have a table of unique customers and monthly sales amounts:

| Customer | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 176953* | 145689* | 167459* |
| Joe | 33489 | 35541 | 31997 |
| Ann | 24573 | 17654 | 120646* |
| Mary | 78735 | 86795 | 84400 |

(over 100,000 marked with '*' for easy ref)

Using COUNTIFS, I need to count how many of my customers made sales >100,000 over a period of 3 months. The answer should be 2 (Bob, Ann).

But my problem is, if I use Criteria_range1 A2:A5 (names) ..what do I put as Criteria1?
...I'm not trying to find all the matching names (ie. all 'Bobs' in the list), they are all unique?

Criteria_range2 should be B2:D5, criteria2 >100000

And if I put the range of months as the first criteria, I'll return 4, the amount of times sales were over 100,000 ... which is not the solution I need.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but since COUNTIFS is usually intended for specific criteria in multiple columns, I'm a little thrown off. (ie. all crit1:'fruits' in crit2:'good' condition...)

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** I am using Excel 365, for those who asked.

---

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the exact question:
*(The table is actually larger, I only included the first few rows for simplicity's sake)*

In cell H11 create a formula that counts the number of customers that had sales greater than 100,000 in every one of the three months. You are expected to use the COUNTIFS function in your formula to answer this question correctly.

The number of customers that had sales greater than $100,000 each of the 3 months: [Insert formula]

Comment: Just to be sure, "Ann" did not make over 100,000 in all these three months but still that counts. So you are specifically looking to count those people that made over 100,000 at least **once**? Can you let us know what version of Excel you are working with?

Comment: Given your requirements, I guess this is homework or an assignment of some sort?

Comment: @JvdV I am using Excel 365, I have edited the post to include that info.

Comment: @Rory yes, it is a homework assignment.

Comment: My guess is that it can't be done with using *just* countifs.  Can you post the entire assignment as it's written or verify that you can't use any other function.

Comment: What does the actual question say exactly? I'd interpret *"I need to count how many of my customers made sales >100,000 over a period of 3 months"* to possibly mean 100k in total over the three months.

Comment: @Rory I added the question. And if that was the case, then 19 of 20 customers would be the answer, but I don't think that is how it should be interpreted. Maybe using a nested formula? But no other question in the assignment has been like that so far. Not to say I couldn't get away with it though if the answer was correct.

Comment: @sous2817 I added the exact wording of the question. No other question has used nested formulas so far, but I could probably get away with it if the answer was correct (or maybe I'm just missing the mark, and a combined formula is necessary... feel free to read and let me know your interpretation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual question is quite different from the original version you posted, and makes it much easier. It's just something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">100000",C:C,">100000",D:D,">100000")
```

Comment: My apologies, I thought I worded it clearly enough, (it was 3 am when I wrote it).
Thank you for the help!! It worked exactly as I needed it. I was clearly thinking about it the wrong way, trying to incorporate the customer column in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Excel365` then give a try to below formula-

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A5,MMULT(--(B2:D5>100000),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1}))))
```

For `Non365` excel version may try-

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(B2:D5>100000),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1}))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Mind you, with not a single customer with purchases over 100000 this will still return `1`. Maybe use `=SUM(--(MMULT(--(B2:D5>100,000),{1,1,1})>0))` isntead.

Comment: I was also posting exact same for non 365 users. OP mention customer is unique so it should work. Still I am sorry if I couldn't question properly.

Comment: OP also said: "using COUNTIFS is required and should not be used in combination with other functions"

Comment: @Harun24HR. Not sure if you understood what I meant. If *no* user has any value above 100000, your Microsoft365 version still returns a count of 1.

Comment: @JvdV Oh! Understood.

Comment: @Harun24HR unfortunately neither of those options will work as I am required to use COUNTIFS in my solution.